# Turning a color bmp to grayscale:

Tags: android

I've seen this code on the web:

```
Bitmap grayscaleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); 

Canvas c = new Canvas(grayscaleBitmap); 
Paint p = new Paint(); 
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(); 

cm.setSaturation(0); 
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm); 
p.setColorFilter(filter);  
c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, p);
```

My questions are:
1.  Is 'bmp' supposed to be the color bitmap I want to affect?
2.  How do I get the 0-255 value of the grayscale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That depends on how bmp is defined (but it looks like that is a correct assumption)
2. gray = (0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b); (from [here](http://www.edaboard.com/ftopic98667.html))